# Netbeans Java EE Context Root adjustment

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, netbeans, netbeans-8

How do I prevent Netbeans from launching development Java EE Server when using the 'Run Project' button to launch with project name as the subpath.

What Netbeans does is 'http://localhost:8181//...' which is not what I want.

What I want Netbeans to run under is 'http://localhost:8181/...'.

How do I edit Netbeans configuration to do so ?

Below is the Netbeans generated web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Viewpoint Secure URLs</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
            <http-method>GET</http-method>
            <http-method>POST</http-method>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <user-data-constraint>
            <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
        </user-data-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Can I get to see your app's web.xml?

Comment: I have edited the post with the web.xml that Netbeans generated.

Comment: This web.xml seems to have very limited information, was there any other config like app server specific web.xml?

Comment: No nothing else was generated by Netbeans.